# How to generate a given number of triplets from a set of items while balancing number of pairs and items in triplets?

Tags: python, combinatorics

We’re trying to design an experiment where subjects choose the odd-one-out among triplets of 60 trait words (trait1, trait2, trait3). At some point, we will probably want to down sample all 34,200 possible triplets, whether that is at the stage of data collection (ie collect a subset of triplets), or analysis (collect all triplets but analyze a subset). Whatever rate of downsampling we choose, we'd like to obtain a set of triplets that satisfy a few constraints:

- (roughly) equal frequency of selected traits
- (roughly) equal frequency of trait pairs implied within triplets (ie the triplet (kind, mean, smart) contains pairs (kind, mean; kind, smart; mean, smart).
- all possible pairs are present in at least one triplet
- traits must form a single connected component through the pairwise adjacency matrix.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from collections import deque
traits = ['kind', 'mean', 'smart', 'ambitious', 'sneaky', 'anxious', 'cunning', 'open-minded', 'diligent', 'creative']    
pairs = list(combinations(traits, 2))
```

## Ways of making triplets

### #1

```
traits_deque = deque(traits)
triplets = []
for word1, word2 in pairs:
    curr_triplets = []
    while len(curr_triplets) < 3:
        word3 = traits_deque[0]
        if (word1 != word3) and (word2 != word3):
            curr_triplets.append((word1, word2, word3))
        traits_deque.rotate(-1)
    triplets.extend(curr_triplets)
```

### #2

```
triplets2 = []
for word1, word2 in pairs:
    traits_curr = traits.copy()
    traits_curr.remove(word1)
    traits_curr.remove(word2)
    third_words = np.random.choice(traits_curr, size=3, replace=False)
    curr_triplets = [(word1, word2, third_words[0]),
                     (word1, word2, third_words[1]),
                     (word1, word2, third_words[2])]
    triplets2.extend(curr_triplets)
```

### #3

```
triplets = list(combinations(traits, 3))
triplets_df = pd.DataFrame(triplets)
triplets_df_sample = triplets_df.sample(frac=1)#n=5310)
```

## Ways of finding the frequency of each trait

### #1

```
print(pd.Series(np.array(triplets).flatten()).value_counts())
```

## Ways of finding the frequency of each pair

### #1

```
all_pairs = []
for triplet in triplets:
    curr_pairs = [set(x) for x in combinations(triplet, 2)]
    all_pairs.extend(curr_pairs)   
ser = pd.Series(all_pairs).value_counts()
print(ser)
```

### #2

```
all_pairs = []
for idx, triplet in triplets_df_sample.iterrows():
    curr_pairs = [set(x) for x in combinations(triplet.values, 2)]
    all_pairs.extend(curr_pairs)   
ser = pd.Series(all_pairs).value_counts()
print(ser)
```

We initially tried to do this by generating all 1770 possible pairs of traits, and then selecting three additional words to complete the triplets. See code below. The problem we keep running into, regardless of approach, is that while each trait word appears roughly the same # of times, the pairs do not.
Is there an elegant solution to this? Many thanks in advance!
[trait word frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGMVc.png)
[pair frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neqii.png)

Comment: Hi figgy! I seem to have misread the question. I didn't realise you were intentionally downsampling. It seems like you want a kind of stratified sample. The #3 of the creating triplets part is a pure random sample, and the variation you get in the frequency of pairs is to be expected, the same as if you were to roll a dice many times, you might end up with an unusual count for a particular number just by chance

Comment: Hi @Mark. Thanks for the input. Yes, a stratified sample, but the question is, how do we do that? For example, the Scikit-learn stratified sampler is for stratifying based on a single class frequency. Maybe there's some way to frame our problem/data such that we can use that one, but it's not immediately clear to me. We welcome ideas!

Comment: @RussellRichie I suppose if you think of each pair, and each trait as a number on a list, and then you could take the triplet with the pairs and traits with the lowest average frequency in the result set, and then add that triplet to the result set.

Comment: that is just a fairly naiive solution though. I wonder if Cross Validated might be of some use in figuring out the right statistical approach?